# NamedQuery with resultClass parameter not returning expected "type" for the query result

Tags: java, sql, jpa, named-query

I have the following named query;

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findSpecific", query = "Select p.name, p.age from Person WHERE ..."

Query query = getNamedQuery("Person.findSpecific",Person.class);
```

When I executed the code;

```
List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

I do not get resultList of type Person even though I have explicity specificed the parameter to the named query. Instead I get the type as Vector containing Object array.

What do I do to make the query explicitly return "Person" type ?

Comment: Wasn't this already covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090094/getnamedquery-with-explicit-custom-class

Comment: That was a different question regarding the overall approach for the implemenatation of getting records

Comment: What method is 'getNamedQuery(String, Class)'? It's neither hibernate nor JPA.

Comment: It actually goes to TypedQuery<T> createNamedQuery(
  String name, 
  Class<T> resultClass
)

Comment: You've explicitly stated in your query that you don't want Person as a result. Use `Select p from Person p WHERE ...` instead.

Comment: But i want to get only select column data and not the entire table columns...

Comment: Then you don't have to expect an instance of `Person` in the resulting list. What do you expect here btw? A list of Person instances with only `name` and `age` fields initialized?

Answer (score 1):

JPA spec says (3.8.6 Query Execution):

> For TypedQuery instances, the query result type is determined in the
>   case of criteria queries by the type of the query specified when the
>   CriteriaQuery object is created, as described in section 6.5.1,
>   “CriteriaQuery Creation”. In the case of Java Persistence query
>   language queries, the type of the result is determined by the
>   resultClass argument to the createQuery or createNamedQuery method,
>   and **the select list of the query must contain only a single item which
>   must be assignable to the specified type**.

So, the query should look like I've already mentioned in my comment:

`Select p from Person p WHERE ...`

If you don't want to retrieve the whole data set, then you could deal with `List` of `Vector` as you do now, or create another plain class and utilize http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html in order to assign only necessary fields.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getResultList()` returns an untyped `List`:

> Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as an untyped
>   List.

If you want your query to explicitly return a `Person` you can use your JPA implementation's `Query` object. For example in Hibernate it looks like this:

```
session.createQuery(queryString);
q.list();
```

If you want to use JPA you can do something like this:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager(); // get it from somewhere
TypedQuery<Person> p = em.createQuery(queryString, Person.class);
```

The point is that `TypedQuery` is generic. You are not passing it a type parameter in your code and you are just using the `Query` interface.

Comment: Hey I do not find q.list() anywhere

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? It is in the `org.hibernate` package.

Comment: I am using the javax.persistence / org.eclipse

Comment: Thx...so i have to make 2 updates...Use TypedQuery<Person> query = getNamedQuery(...) and change to List<T> resultList = query.getResultList();

Comment: Please confirm the same

Comment: I just debugged for List<T> resultList = query.getResultList(); and it is still returning resultList as type Vector containing object array (and not my Person type)

Comment: How does your `getNamedQuery()` method look like?

Comment: It looks like TypedQuery<Person> query = getNamedQuery("Person.findSpecific", Person.class);

Answer (score 0):

The full signature of the method in question is

```
public <T> TypedQuery<T> createNamedQuery(String name, Class<T> resultClass);
```

`resultClass` is necessary to return a typed query (so to specify the type parameter T). It does not do any magic in the query itself. It you only use the `Query` super-interface of `TypedQuery`, then the parameter is useless. Otherwise you can do things like that (without casting):

```
List<Person> list = mgr.createNamedQuery("Person.All", Person.class).getResultList();
```

Again, the class parameter does not initiate any conversion/transformation etc. of the result. It's just required as in Java, type parameters get erased by the compiler and aren't available at runtime.